# Is it mandatory to send everytime an observable from flatMap?

Tags: angular, rxjs

I'm making a service call and based on an attribute in that response, i have two cases.

**Case 1** : return the response with another format.
**Case 2** : make another service call and return the new response with the modified format.

So the code looks like this,

```js
  this.service.getData()
    .flatMap(data => {
      if(data.xxx==='yyyy'){
        return Observable.of({    //LINE 1
          payload : data.objectx;
        });
      }else{
        return this.service.getAnotherData()
          .map(newData => {
            return {
              payload: newData.objectx;
            }
          });
      }
   }).Subscribe(res => this.payload =res.payload)
```

I've used **flatMap** because I need to return an observable in one case. Is it mandatory to return observable in the first case (LINE 1) as well?  or is it okay to return the response directly?

Answer (score 0):

It has to return an observable. At the end of the day - flatMap is just some operator that helps us to form another observable with something that we have. So it should return an observable. Logically it makes sense - if you have a place where you have subscribed to this observable, you would always expect an value to come though in either case (if else).

Comment: To be precise, it has to return an [`ObservableInput`](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/6.0.0-turbo-rc.4/src/internal/types.ts#L47). It could return an array or a promise, etc.

Answer (score 0):

I'll admit I haven't read your question in detail, but what you can do is just return `EMPTY` which just won't add anything to the final stream.

I used that strategy here, where I have a `BehaviorSubject<Observable<number>>` that starts off empty.

```
// create behavior subject OF Observable<number>
const subject = new BehaviorSubject<Observable<number>>(EMPTY);

// subscribe to it, using flatMap such as to 'unwrap' the observable
const unwrappedSubject = subject.pipe(flatMap((x: number) => x));
unwrappedSubject.subscribe(s => console.log(s));

// push an observable into the subject
const tim = timer(1000, 1000);
subject.next(tim);
```